# having issues getting php to talk to mysql set up on a mac -

Tags: mysql, apache, codeigniter

My friend has a mac - we got `AMPPS` set up so he can run Apache, `PHP` and `MySQL`.
We got it up running.  I can talk to `mysql` using `phpMyAdmin`.

I am running `codeigniter` - its working fine - but I'm getting an error when it tries connect to the database

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in
>   mysqli_driver.php on line 126

I have a feeling that I'm missing the mysql.so extension or module in the Apache install or the PHP install.

How do I install that on a mac, or which config file do I need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the mysqli.so module is not loaded. Check the results of phpinfo() to see where the configuration file is, and make sure the module's being included properly. Often times there is a separate ini file for each module that's separately installed.

Personally I'd stay away from mysqli and use something higher level like PDO. I'd also recommend installing something maintainable like MacPorts or Homebrew to run Apache/MySQL/PHP instead of a pre-packaged solution.

Comment: That is what the issue is - the module is not loaded....where do I have to enable it?
I assume in the php ini file?